# Parsing text data and inserting in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, parsing

I am confused with the approach i need to write a python/any script that this needs to be dealt with the below situation.

I generate a text file from the server with column name, time-stamp, server name and column value

```
cpunumber   1437501780  l09fr01 40.0
cpunice 1437501780  l09fr01 0.0
cpusystem   1437501780  l09fr01 0.0
cpuwait 1437501780  l09fr01 0.0
cpuuser 1437501780  l09fr01 1.0
cpudile 1437501780  l09fr01 0.0
```

The table that i need to insert these values is given below. Load id is something i would populate uniquely within the program. What is the best way to parse the above information and load it in the table?

```
 CREATE TABLE `test`.`cpu_util_all` (
 `loadid` INT NOT NULL,
  `servername` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `date_time` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `cpu_number` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
  `cpu_user` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
  `cpu_nice` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
  `cpu_system` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
  `cpu_wait` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
  `cpu_idle` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`loadid`, `servername`, `date_time`,`cpu_user`));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas` to read data like this, and write it to `SQL` as well.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

## Tweak the options here to match the exact file format.  
x = pd.read_table('test.txt') 
## add column names (not necessary if the file has a header)
x.names = ['loadid','servername','date_time','cpu_number','cpu_nice','cpu_system','cpu_wait','cpu_idle']

## create SQL connection.
con = sqlite3.connect('test.db',)
## tweak the options here to get the keys and constraints.
x.to_sql('test', con)
```

You can read more about using pandas for reading and writing [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html).